# Extract sequence of positive hit from vcountPattern in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, seq, fastq

I conducted small RNA sequencing and try to analyze result fastq file.

First I imported the fastq file into R using ShortRead package and converted to DNAstringSet

```
reads <- readFastq("test.fq")
seq <- sread(reads)
```

To look for reads that contain specific string of sequences, I used vcountPattern from Biostrings library. I have to allow mutations and indels for my analysis purpose.

```
hit <-vcountPattern("TCTGCATTTAAGGCAAGTT", seq, max.mismatch=5, with.indels=TRUE)
```

What i could do from here is to count numbers of reads that containing "TCTGCATTTAAGGCAAGTT"

```
sum (hit)
```

it returns

[1] 11500

So there are 11500 sequence reads containing "TCTGCATTTAAGGCAAGTT"

But on top of this, what I want is to extract actual sequences that correspond to the 11500 reads from the fastq file.

How can I achieve this?

```
hit
```

If I just do this, it gives bunch of '0', small numbers of '1', very few of '2'. So I believe this is basically a vector corresponding to the number of hits in each read.

I tried to extract sequence information using this information, but could not make it happen.

Any helps are appreciated!!

Comment: FYI: User is using a Bioconducter package "ShortRead" https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/a-quick-introduction-to-the-bioconductor-shortread-package-for-the-analysis-of-ngs-data/. Not easily to replicate this code unless you can give us a toy fq file. Sequence Analysis knowledge is useful here.

Comment: Dear Holmes, I prepared a toy fastq file that you can download from here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByEbUQPY_T_oci1fbDFHSHQ4WUk/view?usp=sharing). When I tried my script using this fastq file, there are 3 positive hits. Basically I want to extract only positive hits from fastq files. Size of my original fastq files are 200 times bigger than this.

Comment: Never mind Holmes, I looked into the link you provided and I 've got answer from it. sread(reads[hit]) solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

As the name says, `vcountPattern` only *counts* pattern matches. It does not provide you with the location. Use `vmatchPattern` for that. Unfortunately this function doesn’t support `with.indels = TRUE` (yet?) — which is both annoying and a bit hard to understand.<sup>1</sup>

However, you can use `matchPattern` instead. Since `matchPattern` only operates on a single sequence rather than a set, you need to manually apply the function to the `XStringSet`:

```
hits = lapply(seq, matchPattern,
              pattern = "TCTGCATTTAAGGCAAGTT",
              max.mismatch = 5, with.indels = TRUE)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The ostensible reason is probably that `vmatchPattern` is implemented using a different algorithm than `matchPattern`, and that algorithm doesn’t support indels. However, there isn’t really a good reason for not simply providing a wrapper around the `lapply` we’re using above.

Comment: Thank you Konrad, I thought your method should work but it did not. Basically it does not select positive hit, rather it shows all fastq sequences, like "Views on a 31-letter DNAString subject
subject: GCATTGGTGGATCAGTGGTAGAATTCTCGCC
views: NONE". Numbers of this kind of entries are same as number of sequences from original fastq.

Comment: I prepared toy fastq file, which is a small part of my fastq file. if you try this, I have 3 positive hits. Basically I want to extract the sequence information of the three positive hits from this fastq file, and discard most of other negative hits. You can download the toy fastq file in following link [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByEbUQPY_T_oci1fbDFHSHQ4WUk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Dear Konrad, I looked into the link that Holmes provided and I 've got answer from it. sread(reads[hit]) will extract only positive sequence reads. But I appreciate your help!